# Word .dot file and writing VBA7 to connect sybase, got error run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)' method 'ActiveConnection' of object '_Recordset'

Tags: windows-10, vba7

for office 365, we used word .dot file and writing VBA to connect sybase, but got error run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)' method 'ActiveConnection' of object '_Recordset' failed,

our connection worked in office 2016 version.

below is our coding.

Dim connectionString As String

Dim rctRecord As New ADOR.Recordset

connectionString = "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};NetworkAddress=***************;db=****;uid==****;;pwd==****;;"

rctRecord.ActiveConnection = connectionString

MsgBox rctRecord.ActiveConnection

could you tell me what is the solution for vb7 to connect the sybase, how to solve the above issue?